# How to click on a radio button using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, radio-button

I have been trying to get my script to click on this radio button for 2 days now and nothing I try works.

I have tried, `css selector`, `XPATH`, `by name`, `id`, using `webdriverwait` and also switching to Java. Nothing seem to be able to locate it and allow me to click on it. I have no issues with anything else on the website.

What code would you use if you were trying to click on the Radio button ("SearchByParcel")?

HTML code:

```
<tr>
                    <td style="width:33%;">&nbsp;</td>
                   
                    <td style="text-indent:08px;">
                        <input value="SearchByName" name="SearchRadio" type="radio" id="SearchByName" onclick="ShowMessage(this)" checked="checked">
                        Name
                        &nbsp;<input value="SearchByParcel" name="SearchRadio" type="radio" id="SearchByParcel" onclick="ShowMessage(this)">
                        Parcel #
                        &nbsp;<input value="SearchByAddress" name="SearchRadio" type="radio" id="SearchByAddress" onclick="ShowMessage(this)">
                        Address
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:33%;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the *Radio Button* associated with the text ***SearchByParcel*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='SearchByParcel']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='SearchByParcel']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I have already tried all of that. Even tried waiting 30 seconds. It still cannot locate it. I tried this page = requests.get("https://radio-form.lilgoomba.repl.co") # Your site here
soup = b(page.content, "html.parser") 
print(soup.find(id="SearchByParcel")); and it gave this back <input id="SearchByParcel" name="SearchRadio" onclick="ShowMessage(this)" type="radio" value="SearchByParcel"/>
But again no matter how I search it will not find that element to be able to click it.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if there is an `iframe` covering these radio buttons. If yes, first switch into the `iframe` and then perform `click()` on the radio buttons.
Below code syntax to switch into an `iframe` for your reference:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='iframe']")))
```

After switching, try to `click()` on the desired element by inducing `waits`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='SearchByParcel']"))).click()
```

Comment: Tried that, it could not locate that way either.

Comment: So is there an `iframe` wrapping the desired element? What error does it throw?

Comment: Not that I can see. But I also tried.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the Tag label not being properly input. name:null. So it can't locate it. I tried searching by ID, name etc and it cant find any of that info.. <input value="SearchByParcel" name="SearchRadio" type="radio" id="SearchByParcel" onclick="ShowMessage(this)">. Not sure what else to do, never had this issue.